# 3 elements on page, 100vh altogether, one height unknown

Tags: html, responsive-design, height, percentage

[image]

The picture shows what I want to achieve. I don't want to declare the height for the navbar, it might be flexible depending on the device.

The "code" in my opinion would have to be smth like:

"100vh - navbar = available space", make an "available space" div and use the percentage in the typical way.

No idea though how to execute it, anybody pls?

Answer (score 1):

for the navbar I would recommend you to use bootstrap navbar

[- navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

[- static top navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)

[- navbar fixed top](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) , good for your case I would say

then you can simply do so

```
<div id="logo" style="width:100%;height:40%"></div>
<div id="imageslider" style="width:100%;height:60%"></div>
```

Comment: The good news is that I'm already using Bootstrap, so maybe this could work. If the navbar is fixed, it gets out from the natural flow, so won't it cause the logo to be partially covered by the navbar? I had it fixed at some point but it caused these kinds of issues, I fixed them with multiple <br>, but on mobile it was pretty unpredictable.

Comment: I'm thinking as well about making it the way you suggested, but before the LOGO and the SLIDER to put another navbar - empty, no links, just to occupy the necessary space. I'll try doing it this way, if it works I'll accept your answer :) thnx!